# Sharing folders through Nautilus refuses to work on one Ubuntu 14.04 machine

Tags: nautilus, shared-folders

I am only able to share from ~/Public, but using the Nautilus UI to share other folders, does not work for me. Even trying to open a shared folder from the same desktop computer itself, after having configured it in the Nautilus UI as shared, doesn't work. Even went as far as trying guest access :)

Is this a Nautilus feature that just isn't supposed to work?
What might be the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The easiest way has some restrictions as you already noticed.  The [best performance](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba) is a bit more difficult, but much more versatile!  ;-)

Comment: I can't even connect them from the same desktop :) not sure what to take out of the related question. Can't say "easiest way" could be assigned to a way "not working", that would be a strange way of labeling something easy :)

Comment: It looks like Nautilus does not set permissions on the folder you wish to share, so using chmod to set permissions may do what you want. However it looks like its also a good idea to just use Samba for shared folders, as suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1129647)

Comment: I see no missing permissions, and the linked thread is very fuzzy and not helpful, sorry ;(

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you disabled anything in start-up applications that may be used to authenticate your account ? any keyrings , Files , any policy kits ?

Comment: Not really as much as I can account, but it was a box with history that's been through a lot of Ubuntu version upgrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the list of steps I've gone through to get sharing working on my machine.

1)  Install samba

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

2) add myself to group sambashare (which is listed in /etc/group; most likely this is the root of your problem)

```
sudo usermod -a -G sambashare myusernamehere
```

3) reboot

4) Make sure ports 139 (netbios-ssn) and 445 (microsoft-ds) were open after installation and reboot with nmap (optional step, maybe skipped)

5) created a test folder in my home directory , with nautilus. Alternatively could have done same with `mkdir ~/test`. Right-click, Properties, Local Network Share tab, check Share This Folder and Guest Access

6) On the left-side panel of nautilus click Connect to Server. In Server Address field enter ip -address of your machine `smb://192.168.X.XX`, connect. You should be able to see test folder appear in the nautilus window titled `Windows Shares on 192.168.X.XX`

Hope this helps ! Best of luck !

Sources:

[File Sharing Not Working on Lan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251179/file-sharing-through-samba-is-not-working-over-lan)

[Sharing Folders Between Two Ubuntu Machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176248/share-folders-between-two-ubuntu-12-04-machines)

[Nautilus Wants Windows Share Password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10601/nautilus-wants-a-password-when-i-try-connecting-to-a-public-windows-share)

Comment: I also wanted to add screenshots, but apparently askubuntu can't connect with imgur right now. Later, perhaps

Comment: You can just upload them from your local machine, for questions where it really seems helpful... askubuntu will simply host them.

Comment: samba setup apparently has already been in place (installed, and `sambashare:x:124:myUserName` in /etc/group) and ports are open. when I explicitly connect through smb://... and proceed to try opening the "shared" folder, I get the same error message as I initially got, so I believe Nautilus is probably using the smb protocol also when I directly locate the remote folders through "Browse network" in Nautilus.

Comment: @matt yup, I usually upload directly, but last night askubuntu wouldn't take them, and kept saying "can't connect to imgur" or something.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty because this came closest to an authoritative explanation out there, that can be used constructively. In my case, it made me realize everything is configured okay, and I wanted to reward the effort. It would be nice to come up with ways to pinpoint the problem for other cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is very sneaky to humble me what the problem may be, and I experience this problem only on one box... This is not really an answer, but I suffice with using `scp` to copy over what I need, rather than establish a share, for that box. For another box I have, sharing through Nautilus just works. I leave it at that.